# Command Argument not working link button

Tags: c#, asp.net, asplinkbutton

I have a link button and a set of records. When the link button of a specific record is clicked, i want the id of that record to be passed to the code behind. This is the code that i have used:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="Likes" runat="server"  OnCommand="LinkButton1_Click" 
  CommandArgument='<%#Eval("datarow["ID"]") %>' CommandName="Like">  
  Click</asp:LinkButton>
```

and in the cs file i have used:

```
  protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender,  CommandEventArgs e)
      {
         int x = Int32.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
      }
```

But the command argument is null here. can you please help me?

Comment: Is the `LinkButton` inside another control, such as a `Repeater`? Can you include the markup?

Comment: no its a part of an html table. I have used an html table here to display the data.

Comment: I think commandname is causing problem in your case. So probably it'll work if you remove command name from markup.
 and use OnClick event.

Comment: I tried that too. With the onclick function i changed the code inthe cs file to:

       protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)   {
            LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)sender;
            int x = Int32.Parse(btn.CommandArgument);
        }

Answer (score 0):

You would handle the wrong event. I think your **LinkButton** is inside a another control as @greg84 said, for example, you could handle event **ItemDataBound** of **DataGrid** or **Repeater** .

```
protected void Control_ItemDataBound(object sender, ControlItemEventArgs e) 
{
    LinkButton Likes = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindContro("Likes");
    // Write code here to handle for like click
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I see your comments. The problem is your **datarow[ID]**.

Comment: means? how do i solve it. Id is the name of the column. how else do i pass the value behind?

Comment: can you please tell me how to pass the value behind?

Comment: Sorry, for the late reply. What's your datarow[ID] ? You did solve your problem.